# How can I use a helper function inside Razor?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm creating a website using asp.net.
I first created some models, this is one of them:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Subscription> Subscriptions { get; set; }
}
```

And then I created some strongly typed views, one of them look like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<Liquidity_Web.Models.User>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Password)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Password)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.UserID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.UserID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.UserID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

However, this

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserName)
```

would give me `"UserName"` in view. I would like `"User Name"` to be displayed(Seperated with space).
I have a helper function

```
public List<string> SplitHelper(string target);
```

But How can I use that inside the razor view? I tried

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => StringSplit(model.UserName))
```

, but it does not work..
I also feel spacing out the string should not be the responsibility of Views. But where and how should I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be a lot easier, if you use the [data Annotation](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-6) like this -

```
[DisplayName("User name")]
public string UserName { get; set; }

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName)
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.UserName)
```